# Как получить элементы из параметра приложения с типом Collections.Specialized.StringCollection?

Tags: c#, winforms, коллекции, строки, visual-studio

Сохраняю нужные мне значения в параметрах приложения.

Создал параметр с именем "stylesNames" и типом `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`.

Когда работаю с параметром вот так (к примеру):

```
textBox5.Text += Properties.Settings.Default.stylesNames[i]
```

то все работает, но так значения берутся пользовательские, а мне надо сделать, чтобы пользователь вернуть настройки по умолчанию. С обычным типом string это так делаю:

```
textBox3.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["aStyleID"].DefaultValue.ToString();
```

Но как так сделать когда массив?

Пробовал так:

```
var asArray = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["stylesNames"].DefaultValue;
```

но так возвращается целый кусок xml текста. Есть ли какой способ получать значения элементов массива из `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["stylesNames"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, на крайний случай можно десериализовать:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StringCollection));
var strings = (StringCollection)xs.Deserialize(
    new XmlTextReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Element, null));
```

Но должен быть какой-то человеческий путь.